# AngularJS push of undefined

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

> Cannot call method 'push' of undefined

I receive that error when my AngularJS runs the following:

```
$scope.ok = function () {
    $modalInstance.close();
    $scope.key.push({ title: '', gps:'', desc:''});
};
```

I declared my `$scope.key = [];` right after my `.controller` as I need to be able to use the `$scope.key` in other parts of the application. Could someone please point out where I should be declaring this?

`$scope.ok` is my Save Button which pulls the data from my input fields and `$scope.plotmarkers` is what I am using to pull the data from the inputs that have been pushed.

```
app.controller('MenuSideController', ['$scope','$modal','$log', function($scope, $modal, $log) {

    $scope.key = [];

    $scope.createmarker = function () {
        var modalInstance = $modal.open({
            templateUrl: 'template/modal-add-marker.html',
            controller: ModalInstanceCtrl,
            resolve: {}
        });
        modalInstance.result.then(function (selectedItem) {
        }, function () {
            $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
        });
    };
    var ModalInstanceCtrl = function ($scope, $modalInstance) {
        $scope.ok = function () {
            $modalInstance.close();
            $scope.key.push({ title: '', gps:'', desc:''});
        };

        $scope.cancel = function () {
            $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
        };
    };


    $scope.plotmarkers = function() {
        console.log($scope.key);
    };
}]);
```

Comment: $scope (from function parameter) shadows the $scope from outer function

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to pass a scope to `$modal.open`! If you don't, it will default to the root scope, which is not a child of the controller's scope, so `key` is not defined on it or its parents. You can use `{ scope: $scope.$new(), ... }` as a parameter of `$model.open` to pass it a child of the controller's scope. See [the docs](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal) for details. Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

I think you are using $modal a bit improperly.

So you have two controller here - one for the application logic and one for the modal window itself. According to best practice you shouldn't interact between different controllers directly (the case with parent-child directive is exclusion but honestly speaking it not direct interaction - rather your linker function used the controller from parent directive). Instead of interaction between controller in general we should use services. It is just additional note.

What is related to your question - you have two things here to keep in mind:

- if you want to pass the information from the controller to the modal window you should use resolve property which actually specifies multiple functions which are called to get the data and then injected to the modal windows controller as a function parameter. This way you can pass some data from the main controller.
- if you need to pass the result back you should use result property of the modal instance which is the promise (by using your $modalInstance.result.then(function(result){ ... }); ) To pass this object from the modal you can close it with the result as a parameter like this: $modalInstance.close(result);

Hope this helps. For further details you can look at the documentation for the $modal: [Angular Bootstrap](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/)